# How to extract value in specific html code

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I need your help another time !
so i want to get the value for each size (Small, Medium, Large) from this portion of hmtl. I tried with bs4 but the output is empty.

Here's the portion of hmtl code i'm interessed in.

```
<select name="size" id="size">
    <option value="72237">Small</option>
    <option value="72238">Medium</option>
    <option value="72239">Large</option>
</select>
```

And here my code:

```
html_content = requests.get(product_link).text
soupa = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
print(soupa.option)
```

So thank you everyone for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'yoururl.com'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
options = soup.find_all("option")
option1 = options[0]
option2 = options[1]
option3 = options[2]

value1 = option1['value']
value2= option2['value']
value3 = option3['value']
print(value1,value2,value3)
```

Comment: There is a more efficient way of doing this ( by adding a for() loop )  but if you looking for only three 'values', this should work just fine :)